# writing a binary search tree to file in C++

Tags: c++

I have created a binary search tree which gets a text file inputted into it and then puts it in alphabetical order, I am able to print the tree straight to the console but when i try and write it to a text file all i get is gibberish, is there anyway i can do this using fprintf(fp, "%s",rootPtr->word );? or should i be putting each rootPtr->word into an array and then write that array to the file?

Code thats printing out:

```
if (rootPtr == NULL)
        return;
    InOrder(rootPtr->left,fp);
    if(rootPtr->word != "m")
        fprintf(fp, "%s",rootPtr->word );
        //cout << rootPtr->word << endl;
    InOrder(rootPtr->right,fp);

}
```

Gibberish:

> d0ÈõAØ¬Aˆ_0({0¨^Aø@A€A0þAÐ BØA¸z0
>   Û0À›0Ð·0ÉAØ´A°i0 ƒ0Èõ0ÈAÈAØ)A¨[AØ;A@p0`ìAðãAðÓAøOA˜‰0è®0­A0B°s0°Ê0°r00™A
>   u00ýAøßA Bàˆ0X   BxrAÅAÈì0€¼0€½0¨ÊAÐÖA`ÈA8A0‹AØv0@Ä0°q0°É0ˆA ÿA8ü0`ÝA€
>   Bˆ9A
>   Ü08WA€ø0hË0@JA8UAx€é0û0èBøÍ0`YA`XA¨èAÄAp˜0øCAhAA°AHØ0ðWA€æ0ˆ`0ˆEAë0 Ÿ0Û0°g0Èû0ˆAˆGA°Ý0`º0À…AðSA`â0@0A€åA¨ZAèjA
>   ,A8þ0P•AðÙA˜™0ˆQAÈí0øÞ0(zA°(A(}0P¤A
>   ;AˆAÐA AA&A¨¾AÐk0`ñAˆßAB(}A8AH®Aø'Aˆm0Àœ0x“A¨AXˆAxBhµA¸“0©Aµ0Èë0€å08SA¨ã0êA ¤0ˆBè¡0ðÐAÃA8¼AX³0Ð¹AÀ«00©0X§0ÐA8`AøÜ00qAÀB kAÀ‘AÀöAXð0ð¿0Èµ0Èï0ø³AðÌAÈö0@b0€±0@Í0ÐPAZA†0ð Að4A
>   ×0AˆCAhÚ0€¶0ðA¸”0¨$A`AÐ&A@h08½Aó0@1Ax­0€æA°ÕA€ÜAoA€²0ÐAˆÑ0˜‹00Ÿ0`éA`ðAðAšAðä0è‰AÀ¬0€ý0ð¾0`¹0@Ì08ÎAÈü0˜”Ax÷A dAhf0gA lAP›AHA0‰Ah=A
>   B@ÕAÈñ0ðîA`AÐÀ0ÈiAƒA˜0h/AÀ˜AP0`AøBXeAhe0 úA`ïAÐïAÐ¿A@j0OAà–0AØ=Aèª0o0˜~0@Ç08ÌAøÔ0FA8MAðºAÐBAðáAp¡A`KAàœAŸA˜tA8¾0è£0Èù0¨AXôAèeAð]A˜sAØØ0à0ÈóAÐJAxž0ð!A(–0€Aõ0ô0Èþ08ê0 fA(xAp{AèùA@IAht0PŽ08óA
>   0è¥0ˆHAX¨0Ð\A`Bø.AˆAøb0hÞ0 0¨ê0°Õ0°:AxA
>   Â0à—AH±A0†A€cAp~AÐ"AØd0€pA’0˜š0ˆÄAè¯00„0ÀšAà˜0Ðo0@Á0hÒ0@¹A€bA(|AXmAÈA8AÈ°0Aøl0Ðà0°¶A8aA?APvA`·0è­0@a0èBX¦0´0
>   +AØ>Aè©0x0à}0x€00ƒ0pªA`6A ’0°Å0Ø«Aˆ·AðÒA(£A¨ÍA8 A¨ëA8!AðÑA8RA¸}A@³AA8VAï0
>   Ó0xøAðÎA€÷0`á0Hx0ˆOA`ÔAP˜A0B8çAháA˜wA(žAˆ08AàvAðÏAÐ1A8AðAˆÉAp•0Ø×0Œ0h´A€0x’AH*AÐÝA8jAh)AX°0à AH¦AðäAPœA¨A¨NAÀƒAð¶0ÀüA¸§AˆÂA€A8ù0@ÇAÙ08NAØw0ˆÆA8ö0Ø¯AüA8îAÐÁA`7AÐFA¨5A4Aˆ_Aè†AÀ€A`ç0P›0¨3AèqA\A‚A@ÖAÈÚAðØA˜uA…A`%A@È0@:AÈ¦0
>   Ö0ˆ'Aè÷A00`À0 0ˆÏ0€ÿ0Â0_A°Á0ðBˆB°<AÐ8A`Aà£AðAXAðæ0hc00ŒAxB@i0èBøp0ŽAˆl0Ø0 ŒAøÈ0ðÜAÐÞAAðAØu0 ‡A@BP–AÈgAøÄ0Xñ0àzA ¢0°àApyA¨
>   AÐÔAøÑ0p|0¨#A¸—0iA0¥0h@A8ãAØ¨Ah-A(—A`2AàŒ0ÐÀA…0`A0ùAX
>   A€BÐÐ0@.AÈAè 0AÈÛAÈB ŽA
>   ¯Ax‚0XõAHv0`ËAXnAhÆ0àŠ0ðº0@BÐDA€è0@Ã0xŠAXò0ÐêA€òAÐÅAh‘0¨LA¨¸0ðìA@¸A
>   «Ap¢AXAøÓ0ˆÎ0ðçAÀ†0 ¶AÈoAðaA`"A°BèþA¨½A`¿A

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger to see if `word` is not garbage before you write it out? What is the type of `word`, is it a `std::string`?

Comment: Given your `rootPtr->word != "m"` shows support for comparison with string literals, I assume it's a `std::string`. If so, you need to call `.c_str()` on it to match the `%s` format specifier. Even that won't handle any embedded NUL characters in the data: [`std::fwrite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwrite)`(...word.data(), 1, ...word.size(), f)` is an option, but I'd recommend using an `std::ifstream`.

Comment: What type is `rootPtr`? What type is `rootPtr->word`?

Comment: Never mind the tree for now, try to write *one thing* to a file. Whatever a `word` is, declare one of those, assign it a value and write it to a file. Once that's working, take another small step, maybe writing *one element* of your tree, and so on.

Comment: That is some nice output. I'll have a smoke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by simply adding .c_str() add the end of my word:

```
fprintf(fp, "%s\n",rootPtr->word.c_str());
```